# After ECDH with Curve25519, is it pointless to use anything stronger than AES-128?

Tags: aes, public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, symmetric

Is the following reasoning correct:

After ECDH with Curve25519, the resulting shared secret will be an EC public key with a bit strength of 128 bits.

This public key would then be hashed (let's say with SHA-2-256) to produce a key of length 256 bits for use in symmetric encryption. This symmetric key would have a bit strength of slightly less than 128 bits (because the hash operation reduces the bit strength very slightly).

Therefore using AES-256 with this 256 bit hash as a symmetric key would be a waste of time, and the 256 bit hash should be truncated to 128 bits and AES-128 used for the purposes of symmetric encryption. AES-128 would be 40% faster than AES-256, and there would be no advantage to using AES-256 over AES-128.

Comment: Even ignoring the multi-target attacks pointed out in the below answer, AES256 also has four more rounds than AES128 (14 rounds rather than 10), which gives it a bit of a better security margin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The reasoning is wrong, because the scaling of attacks on AES is *qualitatively different* from the scaling of attacks on X25519.**

A successful *multi-target* attack on a system using AES-128—that is, an attack that recovers *one of many keys*—can cost *much less* than $2^{128}$ evaluations of AES-128.  Specifically, using [Oechslin's rainbow tables](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36), and on a [machine parallelized](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce) $p \geq n^2$ ways, the expected *cost* of recovering the first of $n$ keys is $2^{128}/n$, the expected *time* is that of $2^{128}/np$ sequential evaluations of AES-128.  The expected cost of breaking *all* of the $n$ keys is still close to $2^{128}$, but in a real network of users, compromising one of them may be enough to compromise many of them.

In contrast, a successful attack on X25519 is [expected to cost *at least* about $2^{128}$ bit operations using the best known strategy](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/rho.html), even if it is a multi-target attack.  The expected cost of recovering *all* of $n$ keys is about $2^{128}\sqrt{n}$ bit operations, so there is an advantage to batch multi-target attacks, but the cost to recover *the first one* is still an insurmountable $2^{128}$ bit operations.

If you say that AES-128 has a ‘128-bit security level’, then you should consider X25519 to have a *much higher* security level.  But I don't think that's reasonable.  Rather, I think it is reasonable to say **X25519 has a ‘128-bit security level’ and AES-128 has a *much lower* security level.**

**If you must use AES, then use AES-256** unless you have an overwhelming budgetary constraint preventing you from doing so.  If you don't need to do economics, don't [let the adversary do economics](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20151120-batchattacks.html) either.

Consider using the simpler faster safer Salsa20 or ChaCha if what you really need is an IND-CPA cipher and you were going to use AES-CTR or AES-CBC or something instead.  Consider using *authenticated* encryption unless you have a reason not to—really, consider using NaCl crypto_secretbox, just like NaCl crypto_box uses internally with the outcome of an X25519 key agreement.

Comment: And definitely use an AEAD system, even if it's just encrypt-then-MAC. ChaCha20-Poly1305 is fine. AES-GCM is fine. ChaCha20 alone.... not so fine.