# Can you derive a 128 bit AES encryption key using PBKDF2 with SHA-256

Tags: aes, key-derivation, pbkdf-2, cryptoapi

I got confused about key derivation functions. For my project, I need to derive a 128 bits AES encryption key in CTR mode. To do so, I'm using a PBKDF2 to derive this encryption key using an initial information like a password.

PBKDF2 allows me to set its parameters before deriving a key, such as hashing function and iteration number. So, my question is if i set the PBKDF2's hashing function as SHA-256, and specificy the derived key's length as 128 bits, would that be okey? As SHA-256 will hash the input multiple times and produce a hash of 256 bits, how can I get a 128 bits encryption key while having 256 bits output of the SHA-256?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. The easiest way is trimming the 256-bit output of SHA-256.

Comment: Hi, so does the PBKDF2 algorithm do it for me when I specify the parameters as such ?

Comment: For that part is just reading the function prototype `dLen` that is desired length, see the answer from [infortmation security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/53115/86735)

Comment: so as far as I understand, it is suggested that if i use hashing function as SHA-256, the desired key should be also intended as 256 bits right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate the output to 128 bits.

(Or, [consider using AES-256 instead](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59763).)