# Are there any other highly trusted and secure symmetric encryption algorithms besides AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, symmetric

AES is the gold standard for symmetric encryption. It is highly trusted and highly secure. Do any other symmetric ciphers - besides OTP - come close to AES's usability, security, trust-ability?

Comment: ChaCha20 is in TLS 1.3.

Comment: OTP's because they're regaining popularity with the spread of quantum key distribution networks.

Comment: @PaulUszak: not according to the people I've talked to; when a QKD vendor touts message encryption, they always seem to use AES to perform the actual message encryption (because QKD bit rates are just too slow for OTP...)

Comment: There are many algorithms - SEED, CAST5, ChaCha20, just to name a few. All of this is available on Wikipedia.

Comment: Also Serpent, Twofish, Deoxys-II, Camellia

Comment: AES is not the gold standard for symmetric encryption; it is more of a primitive building block in cryptography.  It is not useful for applications to use directly, because it operates only on 128-bit blocks, and it does not provide a security goal that is needed by most applications (even to attain mere confidentiality), namely _authenticated_ encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ChaCha20

- Provides 128 or 256-bit key space.
- The best attack against 6 (128-bit) or 7 (256-bit) of 20 rounds
- Stream cipher requires 64-bit nonce and 64-bit position counter
- Used in TLS 1.3, OpenSSH, as well as BSD and Linux kernel RNGs
- Part of ESTREAM portfolio

#### Serpent

- Provides 128, 192, or 256 bit key space.
- [Best attack](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/wuhj/research/publications/2011_ACISP_MLC.pdf) against 11 or 12 of 32 rounds
- Block cipher with 128-bit block
- AES competition finalist

#### Twofish

- Provides 128, 192, or 256 bit key space.
- [Best attack](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-twofish-impossible.pdf) against 6 of 16 rounds
- Block cipher with 128-bit block and Feistel network design
- AES competition finalist
- Used in disk encryption software, OpenPGP standard, numerous applications

#### Deoxys-II

- It provides 128 or 256-bit keyspace.
- Authenticated encryption scheme with a 120-bit nonce, nonce misuse resistant
- Based on 16-round tweakable block cipher using AES round function
- Designed to provide better security than AES-GCM
- Part of CAESAR portfolio for use case 3 (maximum security)

#### Camellia

- Provides 128, 192, or 256-bit key space.
- Block cipher with 128-bit block and Feistel network design
- Patented but royalty-free
- Used in OpenSSL, optional in OpenPGP and numerous other standards
- Part of NESSIE and CRYPTREC portfolios

#### SEED

- Provides 128-bit key space.
- Best attack against 8 of 16 rounds
- Block cipher with 128-bit block and Feistel network design
- Used primarily in South Korea

#### CAST-256

- Provides 128 to 256 bit security in 32-bit increments
- [Best attack](http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/~anbog/ac12-zerocorrelation.pdf) against 28 of 48 rounds
- Block cipher with 128-bit block and Feistel network design

There is the generic [multi-target attack](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce) on n-bit key ciphers that requires less than the $2^n$ cipher evaluations.

Comment: ‘128-bit security or 256-bit security’ as used here is misleading, because the [cost of a multi-target attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59763) on a generic cipher with a 128-bit key is much less than about $2^{128}$ cipher evaluations.  Consider just saying 128-bit key or 256-bit key instead?

Comment: Why this list ? Why exclude other CAESAR winners or SM4, which most used than any of the above, except probably chacha20 ?

Comment: @Ruggero You are free to add. It is a community answer.

Comment: "Stream cipher requires 64-bit nonce and 64-bit position counter" - there are like 3 different standard ways to use chacha20 (the one that you mentioned, rfc7539's 32-bit counter and 96-bit nonce, and xchacha with 192-bit nonce and 64-bit counter). "Provides 128 or 256-bit key space" - you can theoretically use from 0 up to 384 or 512-bit keys with chacha20, thing is however, only 256-bit keys are really supported in the wild. I would also mention that chacha20 is much faster than the rest when implemented in software.